# Node.js service Timeout issues

Tags: node.js, npm

The Node.js API service hosted on AWS times out at intervals and crashes the server. When I checked Cloudwatch logs, I saw this error come up often.

```
npm ERR! path /app

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! signal SIGTERM

npm ERR! command sh -c -- npm run build && node dist/server.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-11T11_54_06_397Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's my docker file

```
#!/bin/sh

FROM node:16-bullseye-slim
RUN  apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y python3; \
    apt-get install -y python2 make; \
    apt-get install -y g++; \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python;

ARG app_env
ARG DOPPLER_TOKEN
ARG DOPPLER_PROJECT
ARG DOPPLER_CONFIG

ENV NODE_ENV=${app_env}
ENV DOPPLER_TOKEN=${DOPPLER_TOKEN}
ENV DOPPLER_PROJECT=${DOPPLER_PROJECT}
ENV DOPPLER_CONFIG=${DOPPLER_CONFIG}

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:server"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

My package.json file start script

```
"start:server": "npm run build && node dist/server.js"
```

I'm using Node version: `v16.13.2`
Npm version: `8.19.0`

Not sure the cause of this issue.

Comment: Why are you rebuilding the app on container start? That's going to happen _every time_, which is very bad for start times and means you'd need development dependencies in the production image. Look into multi-stage builds instead.